# Who stole my review button? - Review icon hidden on mobile, help icon shown instead

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, design, mobile-web

These pictures say everything. Somebody stole the review button in the small design (mobile).

[image: No review button :(]

And to prove that I see the buttons on large screens:

[image: A review button :D]

Also, this was a recent change (last few days) because previously the review icon was shown in favor of the help menu. Removing the help icon happens for high-reputation (10k?) users on large screens too, so this is probably a bug.

**How shall I continue reviewing on my mobile phone, when I can't see the button??**

Comment: A lot of stuff is hidden on mobile. I wasn't able to approve an edit earlier because I couldn't find the button, or even see half of the popup. I had to open the question in the app and do a manual edit. Also if you attempt to close a question as a duplicate, after entering the dupe link, the dupe target preview and button don't load unless you rotate your phone into landscape. This is on a Note 8 too, so it's not a small screen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like some browsers didn't like our quotes syntax. This will get fixed in the next build, which might not be a minute since it's the weekend. Thanks for reporting this!

Comment: TIL: builds have weekends too ..